# Can I generate points inside my circle?

Tags: python, function, while-loop, module, turtle-graphics

Is there a way to generate points (dots) inside my circle within turtle graphics?
I am trying to generate 10 points inside my circle. My code consists of using functions in the module. I am trying to complete this program using "def" functions.  So far I know I need to use while and if statements and I need to use "from random import randint", but that is it.  I wrote part of the code, but I have no idea if this is correct.  Here is the code:

```
def randomDotInCircle():
    while _in range(10):
        dots_pos_x = randint(25, 75)
        dots_pos_y = randint(-37, 37)
        if (dots_pos_x, dots_pos_y) ==  

            turtle.penup()
            turtle.goto(dots_pos_x, dots_pos_y)
            turtle.dot(7)
            turtle.pendown()
```

Any help on how to create random dots inside of a circle? I wand the circle to be centered at (50, 0) and a radius of 50. 
Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything about [turtle-graphics](/questions/tagged/turtle-graphics), but this is how you can generate random points within a circle.

```
import random
import math

class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return str((self.x, self.y))

class Circle:
    def __init__(self, origin, radius):
        self.origin = origin
        self.radius = radius

origin = Point(0, 0)
radius = 50
circle = Circle(origin, radius)

for i in range(0, 10):
    p = random.random() * 2 * math.pi
    r = circle.radius * math.sqrt(random.random())
    x = math.cos(p) * r
    y = math.sin(p) * r

    print x, y
```

The general scheme here is to generate a random angle, `p` and then project that angle out a random amount from `0` to `radius`. This is just one way to generate random points within a circle.

Comment: thanks for the help. I will try to take the info here and apply it to turtle-graphics.

Comment: This won't pick a uniform distribution of points. If you want that, take the square root of the random number generated to compute `r` (e.g. `r = circle.radius * math.sqrt(random.random()`).

Comment: @Blckknght Updated my answer to include this, knew I was missing something!